# Google analytics page name

Tags: url, google-analytics, friendly-url

Hey guys, Is it possible to use another name for the page that is currently being tracked instead of the url.

The reason I ask is that I have not implemented friendly url slugs instead we have `Products/Details/100` or whatever the page is called. So when you login to google analytics you can see 10 000 hits on `Products/Details/100` but you do not know what product that is without looking in the DB.

So are there any ways of injecting a page name into the google tracking script or should I just implement friendly url slugs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be easier and safer if you just implemented the URLs.

After that, read this [post about canonical page](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).

Answer (score 3):

When you make the initial call to the pageTracker you can specify your own url if you don't wish to use the current request. See the [documentation on the trackPageview()](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview) method for details.